# Cannot turn on fingerprint reader

Tags: windows-7, fingerprint, anytime-upgrade

I have an HP Pavilion DV7 laptop, which went through a troubled "Anytime" upgrade from Windows 7 Home Premium to Windows 7 Ultimate. It required Microsoft Customer Service to install a bunch of service pack updates and disable half of the services/programs I had.

Since then, I've been unable to use the Fingerprint Reader, even though I've enabled the Biometric Authentication Service. I've looked at the Biometric Devices section in Device manager and it says the Validity Sensor is working properly.

Yet any time I try to enroll my fingerprints I am told that the Fingerprint Reader is not connected, and to connect the reader.

Is it possible that the Fingerprint Reader was un-installed (since I can't find a Fingerprint Reader application using the search programs and files option), or am I just missing something fundamental?

Comment: I'm not sure of the problem...I followed this article and could enable it on my lenovo system. http://www.windowstipspage.com/fingerprint-logon-windows-7/